# Regex help : Match all occurrences and format the string

Tags: php, regex

I want to match only this as a first group ->
**e6 c4 aa 7a 7d 11 3d c2 6c cb 6e 3f b5 bc 61 27 e8 67 2c f7**

I have try the folwonig reg-ex: `\s+Cert Hash.*(\s[a-z0-9]{2})+`
but it matches only **f7** as a first group

The string that I am appling the reg-ex is:

```
    [staf]  NotBefore: 1/11/2016 9:48 AM
     [staf]  NotAfter: 1/11/2024 9:48 AM
     [staf] Subject: CN=My Root CA, O=Experian, OU=Hunter, L=Sofia, S=CA, C=BG
     [staf] Signature matches Public Key
     [staf] Root Certificate: Subject matches Issuer
     [staf] Template:
     [staf] Cert Hash(sha1): e6 c4 aa 7a 7d 11 3d c2 6c cb 6e 3f b5 bc 61 27 e8
67 2c f7
     [staf]   Key Container = 9c4336e8-9450-46b8-9bdc-cf70faafb29a
     [staf]   Unique container name: 2d800c871d70eba035d4612cdd5d1a61_48982b62-3
```

Also it will be great if I can get rid of the spaces and get as a result only: **e6c4aa7a7d113dc26ccb6e3fb5bc6127e8672cf7**

Comment: What is the language? You cannot match discontinuous text with one match operation. Match all with [`\s+Cert Hash[^:]*:\s*((?:\s*[a-z0-9]{2})+)`](https://regex101.com/r/uH5bG2/2) and then remove whitespace from Group 1 value with string methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the greedyness of the Kleene star operator:

```
\s+Cert Hash.*(\s[a-z0-9]{2})+
             ^greedy
```

You can capture all the items, by simply making it non-greedy:

```
\s+Cert Hash.*?(\s[a-z0-9]{2})+
```

Furthermore in order to capture it, you need to place brackets around the part you wish to capture:

```
\s+Cert Hash.*?((\s[a-z0-9]{2})+)
```

(so including the `+` quantifier).

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xR7pC7/1) seems to capture the correct group now.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to avoid using lazy/greedy dot matching since it often causes unwanted behavior. In your case, `.*` matches all the rest of the line after `Cert Hash`. I suggest turning that into a negated character class `[^:]*` (**^1^**) matching zero or more characters other than `:` and then enclose the `(\s[a-z0-9]{2})+` subpattern with a capturing group (**^2^**) (and it is advisable to use the non-capturing group with `(\s[a-z0-9]{2})+` since we only need a grouping here, not a submatch).

So, use the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/uH5bG2/2):

```
\s+Cert Hash[^:]*:\s*((?:\s*[a-z0-9]{2})+)
            ^^1^^    ^--------2----------^
```

And the [PHP code](https://ideone.com/ZlkrrC):

```
$re = '~\s+Cert Hash[^:]*:\s*((?:\s*[a-z0-9]{2})+)~'; 
$str = " [staf]  NotBefore: 1/11/2016 9:48 AM\n     [staf]  NotAfter: 1/11/2024 9:48 AM\n     [staf] Subject: CN=My Root CA, O=Experian, OU=Hunter, L=Sofia, S=CA, C=BG\n     [staf] Signature matches Public Key\n     [staf] Root Certificate: Subject matches Issuer\n     [staf] Template:\n     [staf] Cert Hash(sha1): e6 c4 aa 7a 7d 11 3d c2 6c cb 6e 3f b5 bc 61 27 e8\n67 2c f7\n     [staf]   Key Container = 9c4336e8-9450-46b8-9bdc-cf70faafb29a\n     [staf]   Unique container name: 2d800c871d70eba035d4612cdd5d1a61_48982b62-3"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $match);
echo preg_replace('~\s*~', '', $match[1]);
// => e6c4aa7a7d113dc26ccb6e3fb5bc6127e8672cf7
```

Comment: Since this is dealing with hex values `[a-f0-9]` might even be better... good answer anyway :)